# Get a "page url" when a file is hosted using GitHub pages using a custom domain?

Tags: github, github-pages, github-api

How can I get "GitHub Pages" URL for a file in GitHub repository, if there are pages configured and a **custom domain** attached using **GitHub API**? Value of this field basically, but using API:

[image: github custom domain field]

For "standard" repository, it is "`<reponame>.github.io/bla-bla/page`".

For example, there is a "has_pages" property that can be used to figure out if the repository has pages enabled, but I have not found anything called "custom_domain" or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been added in GitHub API in v.3.0: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#get-a-github-pages-site

```
/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pages
```

This will return custom URL, if configured (among other things):

```
{
  ...
  "html_url": "https://your.custom.url/",
}
```